# Show multiple markers on Google Maps Using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried to use PHP and MySQL to show multiple markers on Google Maps. The code below uses PHP to connect to the database so as to get the latitude and longitude.

The problem is the map doesn't show, but once I delete this line, it works without getting the markers: `"var liste_des_points=[<?php echo $listeDesPoints; ?>];"`. I think the problem is the PHP format.

Please help me with this .

```
     <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <?php

     $connexion=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db("survey",$connexion) or die(mysql_error());

     $result = mysql_query("SELECT latitude, longitude FROM appreciation order by id");


     $listeDesPoints='';
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     if($listeDesPoints!='') $listeDesPoints.=','; 
     $listeDesPoints.='['.$row['latitude'].','.$row['longitude'].']';
     }

     mysql_close($connexion);
   ?>

     <html>
        <head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
          <style type="text/css">
           html { height: 100% }
           body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
           #map_canvas { height: 100% }
           </style>
           <script type="text/javascript"
           src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB3is760vHXhki9vS_LpiWAig8a33GP3CY&sensor=false">
           </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         function initialize() {
            var optionsCarte = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.02,-6.83),
              zoom: 8,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new     google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            optionsCarte);

            var liste_des_points=[<?php echo $listeDesPoints; ?  >];

            var i=0,li=liste_des_points.length;
            while(i<li){
            new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: new google.maps.LatLng(liste_des_points[i][0], liste_des_points[i][1]),
                   map: map,
            });
            i++;
            }

          }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%">    </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: var liste_des_points=[<?php echo $listeDesPoints; ?  >]; ,Y es you have extra space between ? > change this to var liste_des_points=[<?php echo $listeDesPoints; ?>];

Comment: i tried it but it's not working.

Comment: i tried with this var liste_des_points=["<? php echo $listeDesPoints;?>"];, the map shows but no markers on it

Comment: I tried your map with my own database and it shows marker. Looking at source code i see `var liste_des_points = [ [47.608940,-122.340141],[47.613590,-122.344391],[47.624561,-122.356445],[47.606365,-122.337654],[47.612823,-122.345673],[47.605961,-122.340363],[47.613976,-122.345467],[47.617214,-122.326584] ]; `It seems that you are not recieving the coordinates from database